# MongoDB Setunion and Group by

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

I have a set of entries where each item has Extra array and each item has it's own manufacturer. What I want is to join the extra arrays each other which has the same Manufacturer.

```
`db.products.aggregate([

 { $project: {allValues: { $setUnion: "$Extras" }, _id: "$Manufacturer" } },

])`
```

I used above query, then each individual Manufacturer is shown like below.
[image]

But what I want is the if Manufacturer is Fiat, combine all the extras(allvalues) together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) to get single `Extras` per document and then [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) by `Manufacturer` using [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/index.html) to get unique values:

```
db.products.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$Extras"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$Manufacturer",
            allValues: { $addToSet: "$Extras" }
        }
    }
])
```